# can i use the node js server to handle javascript client requests as an addition to the application that is already built in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, server

If I'm using PHP to serve javascript pages to clients, can the javascript code use AJAX requests to access routes exposed from my node server?
The project that I'm adding some features (in Node.js and js) is already built with php.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. A client can use multiple APIs and most API can forward requests to other APIs and then return the response to the client. Today, many real world applications use microservices and each microservice can be written in a different language. You can coordinate the APIs under one hostname with a reverse proxy like Apache httpd, nginx or Traefik. Most programming languages can start new processes and evaluate the result.

Comment: Sure, you _can_ do it but to what end? What are you going to do in node.js that you can't do in PHP?

Comment: I would like to thank you first for answering me I really appreciate it. So basically my project is to add a service that keeps track of current users on the pages, to a project that was already built in PHP. The company told me to do it in Nodejs and javascript. So what I did is that I wrote a code that calculates all the events and the time the user spends on every page (frontend side).

Comment: and i need to send all the data to the server once the user makes another request & persist the values right in the database

Comment: Do you have a follow up question. Currently you're only telling us a story.

Comment: Right, my question is the following, since i have the variables that I need in PHP folders(the views), how can I send them to the nodejs server that will persist them in the database once the user does a request?

Comment: One very common way is to send them in HTTP requests either using a network socket or a Unix socket. That's how the Docker client communicates with the Docker daemon. There are many different ways. Search for interprocess communication.